# Interactive PDF Map with Photos

Tags: arcgis-10.0, popup, pdf, photos

I am looking to create a PDF using Arc10 that contains locations for our site. At each of these locations you would be able to click the point and you can then see the photos for the area. Is this possible?

I am thinking something like Google Earth's functionality for shared photos. I feel like this is feasible.

Thanks!

Tony

Comment: I haven't seen this done from ArcMap, but you can do it with JavaScript. This link should provide something to start with (http://forums.adobe.com/message/3368380#3368380#3368380).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am working with right now, however it's not exactly what I am looking for. Based on my time frame I am going to have to make a webmap with the images embedded. This is a good exercise for the future. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

There is an existing ArcGIS Idea requesting to have this precise functionality implemented so I recommend that you add your vote to it (if you have not already).

It is called **[Export PDF maps with Hyperlinks active](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008IjVAAU)**.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible as a PDF form application that uses JavaScript and the Acrobat/JavaScript API. However it requires computer programming. You can also create an authoring tool that can take input from the user/author about the configuration of the application and generate the application automatically without the user/author writing a single line of code. The development of the authoring tool requires additional computer programming work. If your user/author will be creating many applications of this type then it may be a good idea to create the authoring tool for your users/authors.

"[Examples of Interactive PDF Maps with Photos and Animations](https://www.academia.edu/44679586/Examples_of_Interactive_PDF_Maps_with_Photos_and_Animations_A_Reply_to_a_Question_at_Geographic_Information_Systems_Stack_Exchange)" might interest you. It includes ideas for developing software for this type of application.